# Recover deleted exFAT partition

Tags: partition, data-recovery, exfat

I wanted to use my hard drive on Xiaomi TV, and wanted to try format out an ext4 partition. I shrunk the HFS+ partition (disk3s2) using Disk Utility, then erased the new partition (disk3s3) as ext4. However, because of caching issues (or broken partition map), another partition (disk3s4, exFAT) is erased instead of the blank one (disk3s3) created. Are there any way to recover this exfat partition (disk3s4)? I'm able to get some file listed in Disk Drill, but I downloaded them from various sources from the Internet, and it's easier to download them then to sort them without the folder structure and file name. I just want to see what files are on there so that I can download them from the Internet again. For some reason I specified the raw disk partition (rdisk3s3) instead of reconnecting the drive when I realised there is a cache problem, and that results in the exfat partition overwritten. I tried testdisk and unfortunately it does not work.

Log:

```
Last login: Sun May 10 17:52:31 on ttys013
Welcome to fish, the friendly interactive shell
root@Joys-MacBook-Pro /p/v/root# d
/dev/disk0 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         500.0 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +500.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume MacOS High Sierra       443.1 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 44.4 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                1.0 GB     disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      9.8 GB     disk1s4

/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *5.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Seagate 5T (Joy Jin)    5.0 TB     disk2s2

/dev/disk3 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *5.0 TB     disk3
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk3s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Seagate 5T (Joy Jin)    3.0 TB     disk3s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS test                    1.0 GB     disk3s5
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data Joy                     2.0 TB     disk3s3

root@Joys-MacBook-Pro /p/v/root# mkfs.ext4 /dev/disk3s3
mke2fs 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
/dev/disk3s3 contains a exfat file system labelled 'Joy'
Proceed anyway? (y,N) N

root@Joys-MacBook-Pro /p/v/root# mkfs.ext4 /dev/rdisk3s3
mke2fs 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
/dev/rdisk3s3 contains a exfat file system labelled 'disk'
Proceed anyway? (y,N) y
Creating filesystem with 487052288 4k blocks and 121765888 inodes
Filesystem UUID: a4cb702d-2ed1-4cc1-8490-c15c6eaaee96
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
    4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872, 71663616, 78675968, 
    102400000, 214990848

Allocating group tables: done                            
Writing inode tables: done                            
Creating journal (262144 blocks): 
done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done       

root@Joys-MacBook-Pro /p/v/root# 
root@Joys-MacBook-Pro /p/v/root# ext4fuse 
Version: ext4fuse-0.1.3
Usage: ext4fuse <disk> <mountpoint>
root@Joys-MacBook-Pro /p/v/root# ext4fuse /dev/rdisk3s3 /volumes/1
Assertion failed: ((size_t)pread_ret == size), function __disk_read, file disk.c, line 110.
fish: 'ext4fuse /dev/rdisk3s3 /volumes…' terminated by signal SIGABRT (Abort)
root@Joys-MacBook-Pro /p/v/root# ext4fuse /dev/rdisk3s3 /volumes/1
Assertion failed: ((size_t)pread_ret == size), function __disk_read, file disk.c, line 110.
fish: 'ext4fuse /dev/rdisk3s3 /volumes…' terminated by signal SIGABRT (Abort)
root@Joys-MacBook-Pro /p/v/root# ext4fuse /dev/rdisk3s3 /volumes/1
Assertion failed: ((size_t)pread_ret == size), function __disk_read, file disk.c, line 110.
fish: 'ext4fuse /dev/rdisk3s3 /volumes…' terminated by signal SIGABRT (Abort)
```

Testdisk: https://github.com/sclsj/log/blob/master/testdisk.log

Partition layout now:

```
Last login: Wed May 13 16:46:37 on ttys000
Welcome to fish, the friendly interactive shell
root@Joys-MacBook-Pro /p/v/root# d
/dev/disk0 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         500.0 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +500.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume MacOS High Sierra       424.4 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 44.4 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                1.0 GB     disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      6.4 GB     disk1s4

/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *5.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Seagate 5T (Joy Jin)    5.0 TB     disk2s2

/dev/disk4 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *5.0 TB     disk4
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk4s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Seagate 5T (Joy Jin)    3.0 TB     disk4s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS test                    1.0 GB     disk4s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data                         2.0 TB     disk4s4

root@Joys-MacBook-Pro /p/v/root# gpt show -l /dev/disk4
       start        size  index  contents
           0           1         PMBR
           1           1         Pri GPT header
           2          32         Pri GPT table
          34           6         
          40      409600      1  GPT part - "EFI System Partition"
      409640  5868233792      2  GPT part - ""
  5868643432      262144         
  5868905576     1954712      3  GPT part - ""
  5870860288  3896418304      4  GPT part - ""
  9767278592      262542         
  9767541134          32         Sec GPT table
  9767541166           1         Sec GPT header
```

Comment: There were no caching issues or broken partition map. The command `mkfs.ext4 /dev/rdisk3s3` worked properly. You should have used `disk3s5`, but there is not much you can do about this now.

Comment: disk3s3 is the partition I wanted to delete, because it's empty. However, disk3s4 is actually used and erased. disk3s3 is what I refer to as the "new partition" and disk3s4 is what I refer to the "exFAT partition".

Comment: The is no `disk3s4` in your question. I suppose that is why I was confused.